# View Selected (Numpad .) and zooming out with a single shortcut

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, shortcut

Every time I use View Selected (`Numpad .`), the view zooms in ***too much*** in the object I want to center in my view, so I always need to zoom out to have a proper sight of it.

This can be tested easily with the cube in the default scene of blender.

I wonder if it is possible to write a script that handles this (`Numpad .` + `Zoom Out` with just one shorcut).

Comment: I do not know python, but I think I could get by with a little help. Any suggestions or leads about the API commands that will be needed, would be appreciated.

Comment: While not an answer you can try to use Shift+B instead and draw a rectangle of the area you'd like to be as new center.